# Which is the best way to suggest to include an application in Ubuntu Studio's repositories?

Tags: apt, repository

I hope not to be OT, I'd like to know which is the best way to suggest to include an application in Ubuntu Studio's repositories.
I'd like to see in US repos an application which I'm using quite a lot, "SuperBoucle" (https://superboucle.nura.eu/)

GitHub repository is here:
(https://github.com/Vampouille/superboucle)

thank you
greetings from Italy
Manu

Comment: also keep in mind that this has to be added to the *Ubuntu* repositories as a whole, not just "Ubuntu Studio's repository"

Comment: As stated in the answer below, people are welcome to add new applications to the repositories (as mentioned by Thomas above, the Ubuntu Studio repositories are actually the Ubuntu repositories; there is no separate repo). However, upon quick glance, I will tell you we will likely not add this to Ubuntu Studio's ISO image since it is similar in behavior to something else we include by default: SooperLooper: http://essej.net/sooperlooper/ unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @ErichEickmeyer Thanks for explanations; actually, SooperLooper can not be considered an alternative to SuperBoucle, which is much more complete and complex. Furthermore, SB comes as a clone of Ableton live, which is missing in standard repos and releases, with some recording features similar to SL's features

Answer (score 2):

The best way to *suggest* adding an application to the Ubuntu repositories is to file a wishlist bug on the bug tracker. However, this generally won't accomplish much. There are many, many more suggestions than there are volunteer packagers.

In fact, somebody [has already made this suggestion](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=798580).

There are two best ways to *really* add software to Ubuntu:

- One is to [package a snap](http://snapcraft.io) for the Ubuntu Snap store. The link includes tutorials and help forums for new volunteer packagers. Since snaps are cross-distro and cross-platform, it's generally best for the upstream project to do the snappifying. Volunteers to help those projects are usually warmly welcomed.
- The other is to [package a deb](http://mentors.debian.net) for Debian, which will subsequently be merged into Ubuntu. The link includes tutorials, help forums, and upload sponsorship new volunteer packagers. Packaging debs has historically been done by volunteer users, NOT by developers.

Using either snaps or debs, regular maintenance is required to ensure that the package continues to work with new releases of Ubuntu.

This generally works best when a team shares the packaging, testing, and maintenance effort -- many hands make light work. Looks like the upstream bug tracker indicates [other folks are interested](https://github.com/Vampouille/superboucle/issues/48) in forming a team with you to do that packaging.

If this sounds very complex, that's just because it's new to you today. Planning a simple social event (like a birthday party) is much *more* complex and fraught than packaging software, so don't be discouraged. The first step is to link up with a couple like-minded fellows, and attack it together. And have fun.